# How to set the maximum API level for Android in Unity?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I want 2 versions of my android app. One version should have maximum API of 23 and the other should have minimum API as 24. I know how to set minimum API level, but how do I set maximum API. There is no option in the inspector for setting the maximum API there is only an option of minimum API.

Comment: There is not such thing as max API level. There is `minSdk` and `targetSdkVersion`. `minSdk` tells what min version of Android is able to run the app. `targetSdkVersion` tells system what Android API should be used. The best way is to always use the latest version for `targetSdkVersion`.

Comment: @deadfish So if I want to target a particular API level say API 24, then is not possible ?

Comment: If You set `minSdk` to i.e. 24, Android devices with system API lower than 24 won't run.